# Retrofit add Okhttp interceptor no use

Tags: android, retrofit

I found something strange when I add interceptor like this:

```
public ApiDefinition getService() {

        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .addInterceptor(chain -> {
                    System.out.println("into interceptor");
                    Request request = chain.request();
                    return chain.proceed(request);
                })
                .build();

        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(UrlConfig.BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
                .client(client)
                .build();
        return retrofit.create(ApiDefinition.class);
    }
```

Then when I do call a network, nothing print just like the interceptor did't work.

```
Observable observable = apiDefinition.getResponse();
observable.subscribe(....)
```

I am confused, was there anything wrong?

Comment: Other than a typo in `Observable`, nothing especially wrong seen here. Does `System.out.println()` otherwise work for you when used somewhere else? Just to exclude if you have any logcat filters in place that would prevent those from showing.

Comment: That is what really make me confused, it just not worked.I try to debug with debug breakpoint and obviously not entered in interceptor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`apiDefinition.getResponse();` you forgetting to `subscribe` api call. Just getting observable, but not observing it.

```
apiDefinition
        .getResponse()
        .subscribe(.......);
```

Comment: Sorry for that i did't post all code here.I actually do subscribe and get the response.But no print message as "into interceptor" expected.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to intercept Network request call and print them in logcat
you can do so by adding an `HttpLoggingInterceptor` like that:

```
HttpLoggingInterceptor logging = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
            // set your desired log level
            logging.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
            OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                    .addInterceptor(logging)
                    .build();
```

Comment: I was trying to do something in the interceptor and found it is no use.So i try like what i posted, seem to be the same, so i just wonder what was wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry guys, i make some mistakes when i user dagger2 to inject ApiDefinition, so this is solved.